# PHP, cUrl redirect

Tags: php, curl

i want to get an page content with cUrl and after that to post somethink on that Url.
But the problem is: when i am normaly acces the page from browser the page is redirecting.
The page: https://www.orangetext.md/, and when i access it its rredirect to 
http://www.orange.md/. But on orange.md has an ling to orangetext.md and when i click that link its opening new window with orangetext.md thats didnt redirect.
[image]
[image]
My index.php file:

```
<?
$data = array();
$data["foo"] = "ba";

$post_str = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
$post_str .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
$post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);
$ch = curl_init();
$handle = fopen('log.tmp', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $handle);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://orangetext.md/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($response == false) echo 'false';
//echo '<textarea>'.$response.'</textarea>';
echo $response;
?>
```

and the result:
[image]
and what i need to do in what whay that when i will access localhost i will can get the content of orangetext.md and after that to post something on this url.

Comment: sorry, it is unclear what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to build your own form to send an sms with the service of that website, correct?

Sorry, but I don't think that is possible for this specific website, and it looks like they build it that way on purpose. The form-url is redirected automatically, there is a csrf in the header and a Captcha you have to fill in with the form. Changes are likely that it will be agains their policy to use the service like that. Maybe you can search for an alternative service, that has an API for it? (Perhaps something similar where the first couple of messages are also free when you login with an API-key or something).

Maybe you can find an API here:
http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-50-sms-apis/

Comment: thanks, but i just want when i will go to localhost to see the content of this site without redirect using curl post

Comment: Oke, well I tried the curl requests but redirects, also with an iframe, but that is not allowed ('X-Frame-Options' SAMEORIGIN), also tried to include the html of the homepage first with file_get_contents (adding a base href tag for fixing relative paths) and add javascript to redirect to the form afterwards (but that redirects also). So there is some validation/security on that form-page, you have to come directly from the homepage (I think there are scripts there, and referal checking). The easiest way is to just create a bookmark to their homepage, and then click manually to open te form :)

Comment: when i am coming from homepage to this page and when i am doing refresh the page its still showing without redirect...